# Is it possible to run webtests in TFS release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to run webtests generated by Visual Studio during release process in TFS/VSTS? I have on prem TFS 2017 and can not figure out how to run HTTP/webtests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run WebTests through MSBuild tool, you can call MSBuild tool through PowerShell.

1. Add PowerShell task

Code:

```
        param (    
        $tool = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe",   
         $path ,   
         $include = "*.webtest",   
         $results ,    
        $testsettings)
            $web_tests = get-ChildItem -Path $paths -Recurse -Include $include

foreach ($item in $web_tests)
     {   

     $args += "/TestContainer:$item "

    }

    & $tool $args /resultsfile:$Results /testsettings:$testsettings
```

2. Add Publish Test Results task

More information, you can refer to this article: [Running WebTests as part of a VSTS VNext Release pipeline](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2016/05/30/Running-WebTests-as-part-of-a-VSTS-VNext-Release-pipeline)